# Is it possible to see the exact discharge rate of each program on your laptop when on battery (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

I'm aware that one can simply pull up task manager, which contains the power usage of each process. However, this only says if the power usage is "Very Low" all the way to "Very high", without showing the exact discharge rate (e.g. -5W, -10W, ...)

Is there an application that allows me to see the exact numbers?

Comment: It’s simply not possible to accurately attribute power draw the way you’d like. What Task Manager shows is just an estimation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Battery usage monitor in System. Start, System, Battery.  It is a little more refined than Task Manager.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with this is that it doesn't really show me in real time what's consuming my battery the most. Thank you anyway for the information

Comment: The method above is also an estimate, so it is not entirely accurate real-time, but it remains helpful from my perspective.